# How do I make the 'super' key open the app menu?

Tags: linux-mint, menu, lxde

I'm running LXDE on Mint atm, and I was wondering if there is a practical way to make the super key open the menu up, somewhat like it does in Windows.

Comment: Mint questions go on http://unix.staxckexchange.com

Comment: The Meta key normally refers to Alt on a US PC Keyboard.  I assume you are referring to the Windows Logo key which is normally called Super in X11 terminology.

Comment: Indeed, I will edit the post now.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to edit the LXDE menu file, which should be something like: ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml

and add something like:

```
<keybind key="Super_L">
    <action name="ShowMenu">
        <menu>root-menu</menu>
    </action>
</keybind>
```